# Android : Impact of Uninstalling Keyboard Language Packs

Tags: android, package, uninstallation

I am building a utility to uninstall not so important packages from the phone to free up space and resources.
It works on rooted android phones.
 The utility will remove several not required language packages like Arabic , Chinese , Danish ,etc.
 For a user , all language support may not be required depending on his/her native language.
Before i proceeded to the technical part, i wanted to check the impact of uninstalling it on the system.
 I am trying my hands on a rooted htc one x with android 4.2.2.
 Let me know if more inputs are required from my end.
[image: Refer Screenshot-3rd Party]

Answer (score 2):

Waited a while for a reply. Tried it myself after patience ran out. So far I have not experienced anything going wrong with my phone after I uninstalled some language packs. May be it will impact if I try to set the language pack pointing to one I uninstalled. Good for now.